# Angular2 CLI error "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working an Angular 2 project. Now trying to install Angular CLI within the current project with the following

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Problem is when running `ng serve` I receive error

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myng2project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myng2project/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Comment: Please make sure to install the CLI corretly, follow [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

Comment: Ploppy's suggestion to follow the guide fixed my problem - you have to install the angular cli both globally and locally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an issue with version

```
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4"
```

Try to install older one

```
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2"
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and would like to know why this worked?

Comment: Because the latest version of @angular/cli (1.0.0-rc.4) has a bug; installing a previous version (1.0.0-rc.2) gets you a version of angular/cli before the bug was introduced.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like version 1.0.0 was released today, but I noticed this is still occurring. That said, I uninstalled @angular/cli and reinstalled it, but not sure if that also updated @ngtools.

Comment: I've down-voted this as its not the solution to the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman Were you able to fix the problem? I have also upgraded to @angular/cli@1.0.0. Let me know

Comment: still the same , no results

Comment: any one please tell me how can i build abpve command. i have tried like this `npm install angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2`  but it is giving `error`.  also i tried like this but not working `npm install -g "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2"`.  PLEASE HELP ME TO USE ABOVE ANSWER AS COMMAND TO INSTALL ANGULAR CLI

Answer (score 59):

I had the same problem. I resolved it following the "Updating Angular CLI" process in the [npm @angular/cli page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli), that is:

#### 1. Uninstall and clean (global)

```
rm -rf node_modules dist
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

#### 2. Reinstall and play (global)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng serve
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Creating a new project with CLI works, maybe I broke something. I can always move files, create with cli, and try copy everything back in.

Comment: Work for me too on my Ubuntu 16 instalation. Thank you Sr Ruzenhack!

Comment: Worked just fine ! Thanks :D

Answer (score 23):

I've tried everything in these answers and the only thing that worked for me was the following:

> Step 1: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest 
>   Step 2: ng new name-of-project (ignore if project already created) 
>   Step 3: cd name-of-project (ignore if project already created) 
>   Step 4: npm install @angular/cli --save-dev 
>   Step 5: npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save-dev 
>   Step 6: ng serve

Tested these steps in two different environments

Inside of project folder, type "npm install" and wait the installation finishes, this fix works fine for me.

Comment: This was the one that finally worked for me in Windows 8.1

Comment: why the crap is this not the accepted answer I have tried like 20 different answers.  As usual the only answer that works is one on stackoverflow thx so much

Answer (score 10):

This same error can also occur if you upgrade to Angular 4 and don't update Typescript to 2.1.0.

Answer (score 7):

This *absolutely* sucked to work through. In order for me to fix it I had to do a few things...

To get around the `@angular/compiler-cli was not installed correctly` error, I had to take @Ruzenhack's solution, which was to remove both the global and local `@angular/cli` packages:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

But taking his advice further to install `@angular/cli@latest` left me with the same problem, which led me to @SergeyV's suggestion that I downgrade to an older version of the `cli`. Personally, I had another project that *was* working with `@angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.1` so I decided to use that and install it globally as well as in my `package.json`.

Success.

**BUT**...

I was then given another error....
`Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined`

Dammit.

So I took this suggestion [from the angular-cli github issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5131), which was to upgrade my typescript. So, throwing my typescript version to `^2.0.0` in `package.json`, I was greeted with the familiar and frustration-free green `ng serve` output. Finally.

I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 5):

I took me 10 hours of investigatons to find this:

> npm start

The long story to let you compare your investigation approach:

After multiple failed attempts I reinstalled the node and npm and now I have:

```
c:\> ng -v
@angular/cli: 1.3.0
node: 6.9.0
os: win32 ia32
```

All works fine for new projects

```
ng new my-new-project
```

But I have  a compromized project that shows

```
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\profimedica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
```

Because I already have @angular/cli installed globally, I just had to **add it to the package.json** file, using as example the same file from a new created project that works fine:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "http": "0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

The second error is thrown from here because the @angular/compiler-cli module is not installed as a local module:

```
// Check that Angular is available.
try {
    version = require('@angular/compiler-cli').VERSION;
}
catch (e) {
    throw new Error('The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: ' + e);
}
```

I checked the node_modules folder and I observed that the folders .\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli, .\node_modules\@angular\compiler and .\node_modules\@angular\core where missing.

I installed as required:

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli
npm install @angular/compiler
npm install @angular/core
```

I added a log to the file and I see detected version after install: .\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js

```
console.log(require('@angular/compiler-cli').VERSION);
Version { full: '4.3.5' }
```

Now I get a new error:

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
at Class.run (C:\PRO\htdocs\my\api\gen\projects\generated\testknowledge\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:23:63)
```

To investigate this new issue I added a log line in .\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js

```
class CliConfig {
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
        this._configPath = _configPath;     
        console.log(_configPath);
        this._config = new (json_schema_1.SchemaClassFactory(schema))(configJson, ...fallbacks);
    }
```

And I got the unexpected value:

```
C:\Users\profimedica\.angular-cli.json
```

Obviously, this file is not in my home directory, instead of from the root of the project:

```
.\angular-cli.json
```

After 3 hours of investigations and attempts to create the missing files I had to rethink the approach.

I deleted the local @angular module and reinstalled globally:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/core@latest
```

I found that my project has a custom architecture and I had to run 
   npm start

Comment: Running this one line solved all my woes: "npm start". Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Restarted my pc, because Windows.. Was still seeing the same error message when I realized I hadn't run npm install on the project yet, so I did that and it resolved the problem.

Global angular CLI - version 1.0.0-rc.4

Local dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
```

Comment: Worked for me without using older version.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried just about all the fixes in this question. I also tried the one at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli . Same results. So I dug into the error.

I looked at the code at "node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11". This is the same spot where it fails on my project. The line is `version = require('@angular/compiler-cli').VERSION;` This line throws the exception and logs the error `The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.`

The function throwing the error is the `require` function. So the `@angular/compiler-cli` module is not in the current release. I have tried the module identifier `@angular/compiler` but that does not have a `VERSION`. (i.e. undefined).

So looks like this is a bug the angular team will have to sort out.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the typescript to the latest version with

`npm install -g typescript@latest`

find the version of installed package with

`tsc -v`

open package.json and change the typescript version with the latest one and start it again.

Comment: very succinct answer for me and appeared to works for my app.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED !!!

This error is not directly related to **@angular/compiler-cli** as it claims, but to **@angular/cli**, a misleading partially hardcoded and partially incomplete reported error. It is thrown indeed when the version of @angular/compiler-cli can not be determined. But this module is fine.

As I am new in Angular, migrating from .NET and I did not expected so many issues from the beginning. So I started to investigate this one.

The error occure when webpack can not determine the version of @angular/compiler-cli in file C:\Users\profimedica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:

```
// Check that Angular is available.    
try {
    version = require('@angular/compiler-cli').VERSION;
}
catch (e) {
    throw new Error('The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: ' + e);
}
```

You can check your modules here:

```
ng -v
@angular/cli: error
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
node: 6.9.0
os: win32 ia32
```

My package.json contains as devDependencies "webpack": "^3.5.5" but there is no local node_modules\webpack. I have the webpack module in my global modules:

C:\Users\profimedica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack

My error was:

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error:

Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error:

Error: Cannot find module '**@angular/compiler-cli**'
    at Object.

(C:\Users\profimedica**AppData**\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules**@ngtools\webpack**\src\index.js:14:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

**Obsrve that it uses the global package.
I try to install it localy:**

> npm install @angular/cli@1.3.1
>
> npm install @ngtools/webpack@1.6.1

It will ask for missing packages, if any:

npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.6.1 requires a peer of enhanced-resolve@^3.1.0 but none was installed.

npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.6.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.

npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none was installed.

So, I had to add them too.

```
npm install enhanced-resolve@^3.1.0
npm install webpack@^3.5.5
npm install ajv@5.2.2
```

Now, the problem is that the local module is not used. Only the global one. And the error is the same. Even if I have Angular Cli installed:

```
ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
           |___/
```

Now my app works fine:

```
PS C:\PRO\ANG\material\ag-grid\ag-grid-angular-seed\angular-cli> npm start
> ag-grid-cli@0.0.0 start C:\PRO\ANG\material\ag-grid\ag-grid-angular-vseed\angular-cli
> ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried pretty much everything on my Mac until I got it to work with:

```
> npm cache clean --force
> npm install
> ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run "npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save".

Comment: This does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

After update angular-cli I got the same error and I fixed it by call `npm install -g angular-cli` at project dir. After than update `angular-cli.json`, change

```
"environments": {
  "source": "environments/environment.ts",
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

to

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need update your package.json. 
Must change dependecy "typescript" to work.
Last working dependecies for angular-cli:
@angular/cli:"1.0.0",
@angular/compiler-cli:"^4.0.0", 
typescript:"~2.2.0" 
I changed this parameters and has worked

Answer (score 1):

I create new fresh installation in Linux machine

@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 6.10.2
os: linux x64

After I create new angular 2 projects using

`ng new angularhellword`

Project successfully created but when I execute command

`ng serve`

Gives me above same error as shown below

> The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:

`"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"`

`"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"`

It works for me and project run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on a fresh angular 4 installation, after installing angular-cli when I run

`ng serve`

I got the same error. I referred [repository uptodate link](https://david-dm.org/angular/angular-cli?type=dev) and changed compiler,cli and core to 4.0. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this issue via running `npm i`

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

for me the issue was I had created a project with the cli but not changed into that directory before trying to serve it

Answer (score 0):

Check that your local project's 'node_modules/@angular/cli' is not a link to global 'node_modules...'. Remove the local folder (the symlink) and call to 'npm install' again.

In my case it was wrong 'ng new' call with '--link-cli' parameter.
It seems to me that this parameter wont work as expected or I have no idea how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with an older Angular 2 app and solved it by doing the following:

1. I created a new Angular 2 project with "ng serve DempApp"
2. I made a backup copy of my old package.json file.
3. I then compared my old package.json file with the new one. I replaced the new
   "dependencies" and "devDependencies" blocks from the new package.json.
4. I then edited the old angular-cli.json file and replaced the "environments" block with the following, which I copied from the new app:

   "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
   "environments": {
     "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
     "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
   }

Answer (score 0):

This error in the question title occurred due to copy of existing project and try to run ng serve. 
I tried everything above, just try ng new YourApp, and try below package.json - focus on angular-compiler version, below resolved error on my machine.

```
{
  "name": "orderflow2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ***"@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",***
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use *npm install -g @angular/cli* command to install cli.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if installed globally (-g). Same error persists.

Comment: This does not make a difference.

Comment: I think this is the first thing that everyone did to try and fix the problem. Didnt work for me.