# The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Upgrading my project to **Angular 4.0** (from 2.4) with **Angular CLI 1.0** (from beta.31), I get the error below after following the [migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update):

```
> ng build --prod

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

My angular dependencies post-migration:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.3",
```

**Note**: this similar question is about **Angular 2** project: [Angular2 CLI error "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925690/angular2-cli-error-angular-compiler-cli-package-was-not-properly-installed)

Comment: is your @angular/compiler-cli set to version 4? matching the other angular dependencies? have you tried removing your project's `node_modules` folder then `npm-install`?

Comment: I just tried on my local, I can reproduce this error if I downgrade typescript to less than 2.1.0 version. Please update to typescript 2.2.0 and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Indeed, @AhmedMusallam; after the changes in the answer below, everything works! :D

Comment: ah ok, did not realize you answered your own question :) please accept it when you can, I know you have to wait 24 hours or something :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ensure you have **TypeScript 2.2** in your `package.json` and ensure your **`tsconfig`** is properly updated.

**Details**:

With Angular CLI 1.0 installed, create a new dummy project:

```
ng new dummy
```

then remove the `node_modules` directories:

```
rm -rf ./dummy/node_modules
rm -rf ./myproject/node_modules
```

and `diff` the changes between the `dummy` project and your project:

```
diff -bur ./dummy/ ./myproject/
```

Of the many changes, the crucial change necessary to address this error for me was TypeScript and `tsconfig` changes:

**`package.json`**:

```
"typescript": "~2.0.3" ==> "typescript": "~2.2.0"
```

**`.angular-cli.json`**

Change:

```
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.json"
```

to:

```
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
```

and add these new files from your `dummy` project, and install your packages:

```
npm install
```

Comment: thanks mate, helpful approach with the dummy project

Answer (score 8):

I create new fresh installation in Linux machine
    _                      _                 ____ _     **_
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     /** | |   | *|
  / △ \ | '* \ / _`| | | | |/ _` | '**|   | |   | |    | |
 /**  \| | | | (| | |*| | | (*| | |      | |***| |*** | |
/*/   __| |*|__, |__,*|*|__,*|*|       ____|_____|***|
               |***/
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 6.10.2
os: linux x64

Aftere i create new angular 2 project using

**ng new angularhellword**

Project successfully created but when i execute command

**ng serve**

Given me above same error like

> The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:

**"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"**

**"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"**

It works for me and project run successfully.

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution to this problem, and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
rm -rf ./node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

if installing the latest version still gives you an error you can run through the process again of uninstalling and manually enter the version of angular-cli after verifying the newest release in the angular-cli repo. My package.json listed ^1.3.0, but there was a beta version just released and when i manually changed it to

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.3.0-beta.0"    
npm i
```

It installed successfully

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the solutions above worked, but updating npm and typescript globally did.

To update, run these commands:

```
npm update

npm update -g typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message on my Mac running OS 10.12.4 when I was setting up Angular 2.

I also had a similar problem on two different Windows 10 machines. The windows machines received an error that stated,

```
    Node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`.
```

In both cases, I was able to solve the problem by running `npm install` within the project directory.

I went into the command line / terminal and then into the directory where the project was stored, e.g.:

```
    c:\Users\myname\projectname>
```

For Windows I used `npm install` command and in Mac I used `sudo npm install`.

In both cases it took care of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jim. It looks like the second part of your answer "similar problem on two different Windows 10 machines" is a separate problem (despite having the same solution: `npm install`) which should be a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, and the only thing that worked for me was a simple
**npm install**

Answer (score 0):

Open package.json and move `@angular/cli` under dependencies like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Then go to project folder in command prompt and run the command "npm install". It will load all necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed to "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2" from "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0" in devDependencies in package.json file.

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked Like Magic

> npm install --save-dev del

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps please:
Clean up

```
remove node_modules from your project
remove any angular-cli and @angular/cli references from package.json if it's there
Uninstall angular-cli and @angular/cli globally: npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
```

Reinstall

```
Install @angular/cli globally: npm install -g @angular/cli
Install @angular/cli in your project: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli
```