# angular cli not compiling after package install

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

When I try to install a new package for some reason npm removes all packages related to angular cli. 
When I reinstall angular cli I get this error message:

```
C:\SomeApp\Main\WebUI>ng serve

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SomeApp\Main\WebUI\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SomeApp\Main\WebUI\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351136/the-angular-compiler-cli-package-was-not-properly-installed)

Answer (score 0):

when having this problem you can update angular cli at first try.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

be sure to run this commands.

- delete node_modules
- npm cache clean
- npm install

be also sure that this are dependencies in your package.json file for example

```
  "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered the same error yesterday. What worked for me after a day of trying almost all the possible solutions was: `npm install -g -f angular-cli`

It will replace the @angular/cli with @angular-cli to fix the problem for now, then you can work on updating it to the new version. Also check [this link as it has great info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925690/angular2-cli-error-angular-compiler-cli-package-was-not-properly-installed) on this issue.